# Cannot send slack message to specific user via "maknz/slack" package

Tags: php, yii2, slack

https://packagist.org/packages/maknz/slack

There are examples like:

```php
$client->to('@regan')->send('Yo!');
```

But in my case, every message sends to the workspace. Am I missing something?

My scopes from manifest:

```yaml
scopes:
  bot:
    - incoming-webhook
    - commands
    - chat:write.public
    - channels:read
    - chat:write
    - users:write
```